# Eclipse not recognising Lomboks constructor injection

Tags: java, eclipse, lombok

I re-installed my eclipse on my ubuntu machine due to some problems. I now have imported all of my projects and added the lombok plugin to my eclipse version. After a reboot of eclipse, it recognises annotations such as @Builder, @RequiredArgsConstructor etc.. However, there are a few classes which use:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = {@Inject})
```

Eclipse is complaining about the onConstructor_ part saying:

```
The attribute onConstructor_ is undefined for the annotation type 
RequiredArgsConstructor.
```

This is stopping me from running my code as its failing to inject the constructor.

I have installed lombok into eclipse and have all the relevant dependencies in my pom.xml files.

I downloaded lombok-1.18.4.jar from their website but when i run it, the dialog window that comes up will not let me specify my IDE and looks like the image:

[image: Lombok]

As you can see, the box where i specify the IDE isnt available and I cannot scroll down or left/right to get to it.

This has forced me to download an older version of lombok-jar which will correctly open and allow me to specifiy my IDE.

This is why eclipse recognises the annotations mentioned at the start of this post.

Im pulling my hair out with this and the only thing I can think of is the version of lombok ive added to eclipse does not recognise this constructor injection?

Has anyone had any issues like this? Would be great to try and get this resolved.

EDIT:

If i change the injection in the annotation to

```
onConstructor = @__(@Inject)
```

It seems to work..

However, I do not want to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have UI issues, you can install the latest Lombok using the command line:

```
java -jar lombok.jar install <path-to-eclipse>
```

Make sure you also use the same version in your pom.

Concerning your compilation problem, check whether you have configured your project and Eclipse to use a Java version >= 8. The syntax that works for you is only for Java < 8.